# making a smaller sidebar from top so that the top menu is not covered

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

On my page, I have a vertical side bar that opens on the click of the button. The sidebar extends all the way from top to the bottom of the screen. Basically, when i click on the button to open the side bar, it covers the company logo and company name. I want the side bar to be little bit smaller so that it doesn't cover the company logo and name. Below is the code for sidebar:

```
     <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-between p-0">
            <a class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Your .NET Core Application</a>

         
            <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Open Sidebar</button>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
        <a onclick='closeNav()' href="#">About</a>
         <a href="#">Services</a>
        <a href="#">Clients</a>
         <a href="#">Contact</a>
   </div>
   </body>
```

Below is the JavaScript that I am using to open and close the side bar:

```
<script>
        function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "250px";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
        }

        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidebar").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "0";
        }

  
    </script>
```

Below are the stylesheets:

```
<style>
.sidebar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
  padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidebar a {
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidebar a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidebar .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.openbtn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #111;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border: none;
}

.openbtn:hover {
  background-color: #444;
}

#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 16px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
}
</style>
```

This is how my top company name and logo bar looks like:

[image]

Below is how it looks like when I click on the Open sidebar button:

[image]

As you can see, side bar covers the area that says "Your .Net Core A". I want the side bar to start below the top menu so that the entire black color menu is not covered with sidebar. How can I achieve this. I tried to move the side bar below by removing the padding in the sidebar stylesheet:

```
 .sidebar {
      height: 100%;
      width: 0;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background-color: lightblue;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      transition: 0.5s;
      padding-top: 60px;
    }
```

I tried removing "padding-top: 60px;" from above style sheet, but that didn't make any difference.

Comment: increase the value of **top** inside the .sidebar class

Comment: Thank you Yogi. I was not aware of OffCanvas. I will put OffCanvas in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just:

```css
.sidebar {
  top: 40px /* height of navbar */;
  height: calc(100% - 40px /* height of navbar */)
}
```